# Best practice for storing encrypted content on disk

Tags: linux, windows, password-protection, password-encryption

As part of developing a cross-platform application, I need to store username password locally on disk. On Linux, I'm planning to make use of [libsecret](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Libsecret), which makes use of the Secret Service API and takes care of how to encrypt and where to store the data. On Windows, I'm planning to use DPAPI's [CryptProtectData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261.aspx) to encrypt the password and store the cipher text in a local text/config file.

Are there any better/safer ways to do this (especially related to storing the encrypted contents on Windows)? What are the usual best practices for storing secrets locally on Windows and Linux?